# Valid XML example of UDDI queries?

Tags: xml, web-services, uddi

Is this a valid XML for UDDI query?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <find_business maxRows="100" generic="2.0" xmlns="urn:uddi-org:api_v2">
      <name>ACM%</name>
    </find_business>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I test it on http://t320webservices.open.ac.uk/t320juddi/console/find_business.jsp, but the return value is empty. Is it due to the XML or there is no such services at all. Are there some valid query examples?

Answer (score 0):

The request looks ok, so it's possible that there's just nothing that matches your query in that given registry.

It's also a very old version of jUDDI 0.9rc2. I'd highly suggest using a jUDDI v3.2 based product. The UI is way better and there is still backwards support for UDDI v2 clients.

FYI UDDI v2 searches by default with wildcards. In v3, you have to specify the approximateMatch qualifier in order to enable wildcards.

http://juddi.apache.org/ There's a link to download the latest, along with links to a live demo instance

Comment: where can I find some valid request examples (can really return something instead of empty)?

Comment: Try just '%' without quotes for the name field

Comment: I tried this, but the result is still empty:                                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <businessList generic="2.0" operator="jUDDI.org" xmlns="urn:uddi-org:api_v2">
   <businessInfos/>
  </businessList>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Again it looks valid. Older versions of juddi did not come with anything preregistered, so it's more than probable that nothing is registered at that node. try this http://uddi-jbossoverlord.rhcloud.com/ which routes web service requests to http://uddi-jbossoverlord.rhcloud.com/juddiv3/ The root url has an (Create then Advanced) page to let you hand jam in queries and try them out.